Can light have mass when moving through a fiber optic?
Light on it's own does not have mass as we understand it. Light also never travels in a straight line (diffraction and spacetime curvature) and light travels at a constant speed.  This is what I understand to be true based on my limited knowledge of the topic.
Thinking way out-of-the-box, I was wondering about the idea of light traveling though a fiber optic.  The light is bent and channeled in many directions while in the fiber optic. The light also has more resistance due to the fiber optic it travels within.
Along these lines of thinking, it makes me wonder if light could be thought of as temporarily having or inheriting the properties and/or "mass" of the fiber optic medium that it travels through?

Light never travels in a straight line (diffraction and spacetime curvature) With spacetime curvature, the equivalent of Euclidean straight lines are geodesics, and light travels on them. There are no “straighter” lines that it could travel on.

I think the concept has been discussed wrt light slows down in a medium ... but most counter by arguing the EM wave is just interacting within the medium which takes time.

Hi Tim. It's a great question but it has been asked before. have a look at the duplicate I've linked and if you don't think it answers ping me and I'll reopen this.
